# Error in alignment when converting div to table

Tags: html, yii, html-table

I'm experiencing error in alignment when try to convert div to table.
How to solve?

```
<tr><td>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'gender'); ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'M');?>
        <?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'gender',array('value'=>'M')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'F');?>
        <?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'gender',array('value'=>'F')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'gender'); ?>
        </td></tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Are we supposed to see what you get in your output? show some picture or something so we can know what is wrong

Comment: can u please tel me how to align in straight line

Comment: Isn't this more of a css problem?

Comment: Yeah I would say you need to view the source code that gets generated and put that on here so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the label and the radio button is wrapped by a div, or the element has the style property display:block;